# Vue Material: remove dropdown arrow from md-select component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-material

Is it possible to remove dropdown arrow from `md-select` component of **Vue Material?**

i.e.to make it from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the class of your md-select is md1, then the arrow is a descendant of md-select you can do the following in your css file:

```
md1 .md-select-icon {
    display: none;
    // rest of your style below
}
```